# VB6 oracle query returns no value

Tags: sql, oracle, vb6, oracle-sqldeveloper

I fetched the query in immediate window in vb6, it works fine in oracle sql developer. but when i try to run the query using vb6 application. it does not return any value.

query starts with something like
"with xyz as (select & _
" & _
" ) & _
" select statement based on xyz"

Comment: Maybe CTE isn't supported; try to switch to an inline view.

Comment: Then you are not executing the same query.  The fact that the client is VB should not matter.  The query string between the two application is 100% the same?

Comment: Does "with" need to be prefixed with a semicolon if its not the first statement, as it does in sqlserver? If so, there might be some wrapping going on that adds something before the query. Try adding a semicolon, like ";with"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Oracle Client successfully installed locally on your PC and that it can successfully connect to your Oracle DB. Use those connection parameters to set up your DSN (or DSN-less) connection within your code or in ODBC Administrator and then run your SQL using the Execute statement.